# Typescript remap array to object with intellisense on keys

Tags: typescript

I am currently having some trouble understanding [Typescript Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), where they list that "Key remapping" is possible, but when actually trying that with a array, it just errors with `Type '"key"' cannot be used to index type 'A[E]'`.

Note: this is a *types* question, not a *runtime* question.

Example Code:

```
interface ListEntry {
  key: string;
  prop: string;
}

type MapListEntryArrayToRecord<A extends ListEntry[]> = {
  // Error "Type '"key"' cannot be used to index type 'A[E]'"
  [E in keyof A as A[E]['key']]: A[E]['prop'];
};

const input: ListEntry[] = [
  { key: 'key1', prop: 'Prop1' },
  { key: 'key2', prop: 'Prop2' },
];

function someFunction<List extends ListEntry[]>(list: List): MapListEntryArrayToRecord<List> {
  // some implementation
  const ret: Record<string, ListEntry['prop']> = {};
  for (const { key, prop } of list) {
    ret[key] = prop;
  }

  return ret as MapListEntryArrayToRecord<List>;
}

const mapped = someFunction(input);

// expecting intellisense for all available keys
mapped;

// example of what i would expect
const expectedOutput = {
  key1: 'Prop1',
  key2: 'Prop2',
};

// expecting intellisense for all available keys
expectedOutput;
```

PS: i tried to search for a answer, but could not find any typescript examples on how to do this.

Comment: When you write `const input: ListEntry[] = [/**/]` you're telling the compiler that `input` is of type `ListEntry[]` and that it cannot and should not keep track of the literal types of any values or properties.  If you do care about this you should write `const input = [/**/] as const`.  Once you do that, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlEAXm) would be how I'd suggest you proceed.  If that works for you I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First the `input` object. If you use an explicit type, all information about specific values of the object you assign to it is lost. So we have to remove the type and add `as const`.

```
const input = [
  { key: 'key1', prop: 'Prop1' },
  { key: 'key2', prop: 'Prop2' },
] as const;
```

Using `as const` will convert the array to `readonly`. We will have to modify the generic types to accept both normal and `readonly` arrays.

```
type MapListEntryArrayToRecord<A extends readonly ListEntry[]> = {
  /* ... */
};

function someFunction<List extends readonly ListEntry[]>(list: List): MapListEntryArrayToRecord<List> {
  /* ... */
}
```

Now to your original question. TypeScript has problems with knowing that `A[keyof A]` has a `key` property. This boils down to the fact that generic types indexed with keys of generic types and similar expressions will often not be fully evaluated by the compiler.

So we have to remind TypeScript that this property exists by explicitly checking.

```
type MapListEntryArrayToRecord<A extends readonly ListEntry[]> = {
  [E in keyof A as A[E] extends { key: infer K extends string } ? K : never]: 
    A[E]['prop'];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=3&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5gKLigT2QG8AoZZAawnwC5kspQBzAbjOQAcoB7Duh5mwC%20JEmHwcUAWTgd0WXGAIBBKFDj4AKtwBKEBNygATADzLkEAB6QQRjMigQ4R7iAA2heTjz4A2gF0APmQAXmJ2X2xkUEpqbhhkczh7ZUj-C2sIW3siWNpokBhoZABpDJs7eiVmZCFkAH5S5DoQCAA3aH86VOx-XwByLl5%20-2E2EgMQLAKOAFcwUORfdlyqfP61gEZ%20gBpOHj5kfoAFA%203anZW8ug3qACZd-d4b094Hi5J05ORJrHGYWYgBBgYCuejcAC2EAAYoDgaCQCYvOUspVHM5XB40JhvEo-EEABRuHF0LwASjoMjkOMUKjUGm0egMxiROOCpHIAHpOeCodEIRw3BAoeA4CDXOxfgtHGA6EzDKYBCAmHsvLS-IMDiNgmEiEI2OQYIZkASpcQ8nshhxash4shiVgyeFyOQZb41ukwlaDbVRK6IGBZlAQA4A8hvlS1T5VOotLp9ArWVhAsJRGaIbJJEZFhhITC4eKQATQHMwGTxtyMpJ4cqCpA3A6shgUEaoOGG%20G2nBgG44AAjIV5DAkDMcLMVnlWOACwd2gDuAAsxdFkHPuLM3NmrNWwBNXNNt-pIEYAPLzUuLDl5TYvM67dhrO63t73-WiSuHmtMOsQBuYJstsacAdnAXY9v2g5rMOn7HmeYCliwQA)

Comment: I don't think you want `A[E] extends { key: infer K extends string } ? K : never`, since one of `E` will be `number` and then you'll get a big union, I think.  Check the inferred type of `mapped.key1`, for example. Really you want just the numeric-like keys `E`, such as `E in Extract<keyof A, \`${number}\`>`

Comment: @jcalz Ahh, took me some time to understand the issue. But yes, the `Extract<>` solution works better

Comment: Thanks the "remind typescript this property exists" (using `infer`) works, but the Extract solution does not, it outputs numbers as keys, which is not what i wanted, i wanted the values from `key` to be the keys, not the index.

Comment: actually after some more testing, this solution kinda works, but somehow it creates a union of all input "prop" in every key, like `mapped.key1` is of type `"Prop1" | "Prop2"`, which should not be correct

Comment: @hasezoey take a look at [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlEAXm)

Comment: thanks that playground one works

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the accepted answer really should include `E in Extract<keyof A, \`${number}\`> as A[E]['key']` as noted in the first comment - this produces a map with properly mapped keys, not a weird union typed thing